# Prevent DialogFragment from being dismissed when the free area is touched

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, android-architecture-navigation

By default, when a `DialogFragment` is shown, there's a large, unoccupied area that's shown with a semitransparent overlay. When the user touches this, the `DialogFragment` is dismissed. How can I prevent this behaviour? Note that I still want the user to be able to close the dialog using the system back button.

I tried already with

```
isCancelable = false // set inside my DialogFragment
```

In this case the `DialogFragment` is not dismissed when one touches on the free area, exactly as I want it. However as a negative side effect also the system back button stops working. So, how to only disable dismissing the dialog when touching the free area, but at the same time still keep the system back button enabled?

Hint: I am using the Android Navigation component (latest `2.3.0-alpha04`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use this:

```
setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)
```

Comment: thanks, that works. hint for others: this needs to be set on the dialog created in e.g. `DialogFragment.onCreateDialog`, not at the `DialogFragment` itself (where it isn't available)